# Is it possible in Google Apps Script to programmatically fill a shape in Google Slides with a gradient?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I would like to be able to, on each individual slide, set a rectangle shape that has a randomly generated gradient, but I can't find any functions to set shape fill to a gradient? Am I just overlooking it, or has it not been implemented?

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there are no methods for setting the gradient color using Google Slides service and Google Slides API. This has already been reported to Google issue tracker as follows.

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179455333
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191392267

#### Workaround:

From `I would like to be able to, on each individual slide, set a rectangle shape that has a randomly generated gradient`, in this case, as the current workaround, how about the following flow?

1. Manually create multiple shapes by changing the gradient color.
2. When you want to put a shape on a slide, one of the shapes you have already created is randomly selected and copied, and put on the slide.

   - In this case, you can change the size of the shape after the shape was put.